# jquery trapping allow only letters

Tags: jquery

I am creating a web page where I have a input text field in which I want to allow only alphabet..

How can i make it using jQuery??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**[jquery.inputmask](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/inputmask)** is a jquery plugin which create an input mask. That is allow only input according to a specific pattern. e.g, date, text, numbers zipcode etc.

there is also **[another (older) version](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)**:

> It allows a user to more easily enter
>   fixed width input where you would like
>   them to enter the data in a certain
>   format (dates,phone numbers, etc). It
>   has been tested on Internet Explorer
>   6/7, Firefox 1.5/2/3, Safari, Opera,
>   and Chrome.A mask is defined by a
>   format made up of mask literals and
>   mask definitions. Any character not in
>   the definitions list below is
>   considered a mask literal. Mask
>   literals will be automatically entered
>   for the user as they type and will not
>   be able to be removed by the user.

Comment: +1 plugin link... I knew Masked Input Plugin, but this is way better

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/Hb44n/)

We bind to input change then take a look at the current string. We walk over the string and append any alphabetical characters to the output variable and return that.

```
$("#textField").bind("input", function(event) {
   var out = "";
   var str = this.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (/[A-Za-z]/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
            out = out.concat(str.charAt(i));    
        }
    }
    this.value = out;
 });
```

Comment: At *least* four things wrong with that: 1. `keyup` is the wrong event (think key repeat, when you hold down a key). 2. Magic numbers 65 and 90. 3. The magic numbers are wrong (lower case? accented characters?). 4. It doesn't handle it if the user right-clicks and chooses "paste" from a context menu, as the vast majority of browsers and OSes let them do.

Comment: @TJCrowder I fixed a few of those. I didn't think of paste