# jQuery clear input text on focus

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I have this `jQuery` script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
    $('.letters').keyup( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val().length > 1)
            $this.val($this.val().substr(0, 1));
            $(this).next('input').focus();
        });
});
```

It will set focus on the first `input='text'` field on page load. When a user enters a character it will move focus to the next following input field. It will also limit the number of characters allowed in each field (currently 1 character).

I wonder if it's possible to clear the current value of the input field on focus. Both when a user clicks with the cursror to focus the field but also when the `$(this).next('input').focus();` sets focus on the next input field.

Also is it possible to validate the characters to only allow alphabetical characters?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To filter the input, use

```
​$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if( !/[a-z]|[A-Z]/.test( String.fromCharCode( e.which ) ) )
        return false;
});​​​​​​​​
```

To clear the input field on `click` & `focus`, use

```
$('input').on('click focusin', function() {
    this.value = '';
});
```

Be aware of that this event will fire twice, when you click into a non-focused *input control* in its current form.

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/xbeR2/

Comment: The keydown function give's me `SyntaxError: illegal character` `});`

Comment: Probably. I'll take a closer look then! Thank you.

Comment: @David: added a demo link.

Comment: Would it be possible to exclude Backspace and Delete keys from that validation?

Answer (score 11):

To answer your focus question, yes you can do that:

```
$("input").focus(function() {
  this.value = "";
});
```

To answer the only allow letters question, this has [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980038/allow-text-box-only-for-alphabets-using-jquery) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827535/jquery-trapping-allow-only-letters) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016693/allow-only-letters-and-spaces-jquery-validation-plugin).

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm! I will take a look at your link also.

Comment: @David Glad you got it worked out. Don't forget to mark one of the solutions as the accepted answer so others know your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var search_text_s = "WYSZUKAJ";

  // author ZMORA
  // search input focus text
  $("#searchClear").focus(function() {
    if(this.value == search_text_s){
      this.value = "";
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    if(this.value != search_text_s){
      this.value = search_text_s;
    }
  });
});
```