# How to clear default value of form when the user starts typing (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do I get the form field (with default text "default") to be cleared when the user starts typing? 
I attached my code below. I want it to have similar functionality to the .prompt() command.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>

</style>
<script>
    $ (function() {
        var dialog;
        dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height:300,
            width:350,
            modal:true,

        });
        form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();
            $( "#placeName" ).append(name.val);
        }); 

        $ ( "#clickMe" ).button().on("click", function(){
            dialog.dialog("open");
        }); 


    });


</script>
```

Here is where the form is made, and the value is set to "default"

```
  <body>    
      <div id="dialog-form" title="create user"> <!--starts out hidden-->
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="default" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        </form>
    </div>

    <button id="clickMe">Click!</button>
    <br><br><hr><br><br>
    <div id="placeName"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you could expand a little on what **exactly** the requested code should do, I could point you in the right direction, but there is some undeniable vagueness here.

Answer (score 1):

`<input {Other attributes} placeholder="default" />`

You need to, however, remove the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically don't want `placeholder` but as `value`.

```html
<div id="dialog-form" title="create user"> <!--starts out hidden-->
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="default"
 class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" onfocus="this.onfocus=null;this.value=''" onblur="this.value=this.value||'default'">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The only thing I see here, is that the 'placeholder' is gone once the user clicks within the box once. It is easy enough to implement it though.

Comment: No, I am saying that once the user has clicked on the box, if they lose focus, the text is still gone. The OP isn't as clear as he could be.
Also, please don't be so aggressive.

Comment: ohh no no.. didnt mean to aggressive.. actually I didnt get your point so I asked. now I got your point. correct but thats what OP asked he wants the `prompt(a,b)` like functionality in regards to clearing out default once focused and above code provides that.

Comment: Sorry If I misinterpreted your comment, It seemed a little aggressive to me. And I guess you have a point, the OP does have a few too many ways of being read.

Comment: Sorry If the comment sounded aggressive, actually initially I had just `so whats your point` then thought could be aggressive so added later part for asking clarification. Yes, OP mentioned kinda `hidden` way he wants the prompt(a,b) like functionality in regards to clearing out default once focused

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, I would have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978723/2545832).

For you it'd be something like:

```
$('input').on('click focusin', function() {
    this.value = '';
});
```

if you really want to have a text in your input and not a `placeholder` but wasn't clear in your question.

Comment: This is one way of going about it, but it is completely unnecessary, especially when a HTML standard attribute suffices.

Comment: That's totally true, I'd never use that but I thought it was what he asked for! :D

Comment: As I'm sure you know, some people are a little odd in their choice for solutions, hence I wont downvote, because it does do what the OP asked, just in a slightly obtrusive way.

Comment: Kind from you! Actually, I found the question on the triage and as I read it, I  wasn't sure of what was asked and marked it "To be improved" and I cannot figure out that he asked for such a simple thing that you can just google... That's why I answered with this not elegant answer.